# Add and Remove Discord Roles by Command

Tags: javascript, discord, roles

OK, so possibly silly question here, but I'm thoroughly confused.

I'm trying to set up a command so that certain roles are added and removed when it is run, eg:
Add ID1, ID2, ID3
Remove ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7
Display "This user is set as (ROLE), and will need to open a ticket to change it"

I have the below file, but can't work out how to edit it to automatically select certain roles rather than having to apply them manually:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.permissions.has(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry! :disappointed: :broken_heart: You don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );

  let rMember =
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    message.guild.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
    message.guild.members;
  let role =
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name == args[1]) ||
    message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id == args[1]) ||
    message.mentions.roles.first();
  if (!role)
    return message.channel.send(
      "Is this user a SS, SD, Sub or Dom?"
    );

  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry, friend :broken_heart: :shrug: I don't have permission to perform this command!"
    );

  if (rMember.roles.has(role.id)) {
    return message.channel.send(
      `$rMember.displayName), already has this role!`
    );
  } else {
    await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    message.channel.send(
      `${rMember.displayName} is set as a Switch Sub and will need to open a ticket if they wish to change this`
    );
  }

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(colours.redlight)
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL())
    .addField("Moderation:", "Member set as SS")
    .addField("Date:", message.createdAt);
    
  let sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.name === "beans-the-frog"
  );
  sChannel.send(embedVariable);
};

module.exports.config = {
  name: "ss",
  description: "Sets a user as a (ROLE)",
  usage: "beans addrole",
  accessableby: "Staff Team",
  aliases: ["ss"],
};
```

Comment: I am confused myself here , let me get few things straight here , so imagine you mention 4 roles and in this 4 roles you mentioned you wanna get first 2 roles removed and the another 2 roles added. But if they have roles which were supposed to be added then get them removed and which was supposed to be removed will not be removed and they have open a ticket ? or vise versa

Comment: Essentially, yes.  The command needs to run that it will apply certain roles, and remove others, and then give the message reminding them to open a ticket if they want to swap later on